# How to prevent duplication against dayClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Before questioning, I reveal that I am a beginner.

I'm using fullCalendar for the first time.

When I clicked on the date, I made the event registration.

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar
   ({
      dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
      {

         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', 
         {
             title : '휴진',
             allDay : true,
             start: date, //specify start date
             stick : true,
             backgroundColor: '#fe4978'
          });
      }
   });
```

This code allows duplication in event registration.

Once an event is registered for a specific date, I would like to prevent the event from being registered thereafter.

I have seen docs related to removeEvent, but I do not know how to write the code.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me a guide.

Comment: what you meant by prevent being registered thereafter?it will only register in a specific date right?

Comment: Why are you calling full calendar within fullcalendar? Typically, you initialise it once and using for the duration of your page

Comment: What I would like to implement now is the hospital shutdown configuration function. There are no other events.

Comment: You do not have to worry about refreshing because you can register for a month's retreat date and press the last button to turn it over to the next month.

Comment: What is the purpose of the dayClick callback function?

Comment: I'm adding an event, adding the clicked date to obj in array form and storing the values ​​in DB. for example, If you registered for 2 and 5 in November, {"2017-11-2","2017-11-5"}

Comment: The length of obj is variable. (Closed registration date added)

Comment: That is, you can add a variable value to obj and add that obj to the DB. @cdoshi

Comment: Ok, but then you do not need to initialise another fullcalendar right?

Comment: yeah, Only prevent duplication against dayClick

Comment: are you trying to avoid overlapping of events on a date?

Comment: Yes. I'm still writing the example logic, but it's not working. I just want to prevent other events from being added if the event is registered. @vrn53593

Comment: are the events stored in db and called into an array?

Comment: If you set all the events and click the "Final registration button", the value will be sent to the controller and stored in the DB.

Comment: However, note that the value is added to the OBJ every time the event is registered. (Obj has a variable length.)

Comment: have you tried *overlap:false* property in the event object?

Comment: No. I don't know that information (`overlap:false`)

Comment: check this [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object)

Comment: OK, and I will try that. wait please hh

Comment: @vrn53593 please check link : https://imgur.com/a/CX9CE

Comment: What I understand is the ability to disable size adjustments for events. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you @won.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

       dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {

            if(event.start <= date && event.end >= date) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
     }
 });
```

Updated:

Add a function before you store the selected event into the object.

```
function IsDateHasEvent(date) {
    var allEvents = [];
    // add your calendar events into the array. 
    allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {
        return +v.start === +date;
    });

    return event.length > 0;
}
```

and change your code as follows.

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

    if (!IsDateHasEvent(date)) {
         // No previous event on this date. 
        selectedDate = date;
        eventData = {
             title: title,
             start: start,
             stick : true,
             backgroundColor: '#fe4978',
             overlap: false,
        };

         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
         // add new appointment code.
        //$("#divAddNewAppointment").dialog("open");
    }
    else {
        //$('<%= "#" + lblMessage.ClientID%>').html(" your error msg");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        $("#divMessage").dialog("open");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Let's apply this. I'm really sorry, can I ask you one more question?

Comment: sure, what is it?

Comment: If you can answer the question, please refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918004/how-to-insert-the-value-retrieved-from-db-into-defaultdate

Comment: bro, are you here?